# Regex: Get First Param

Tags: regex

My Regex:

```
#\<param name\=\"src\"+.+\"\s\/\>#
```

The problem is that stops at the second `/>` but I want just the first `<param>`.

```
  <param name="example" src="hello.swf" />
  <param name="stuff2" />
```

So how should I get just the first param?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably something like this...

```
#param name="([a-zA-Z0-9]+)" src="(.*?)"#is
```

Your result should be in $match[2]